# How to use a YouTube player view as a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio, youtube-api

I was trying to use two `YouTubePlayerViews` in one activity, but it doesn't *seem* to be possible without a fragment. I tried the code below.

1. Created a New layout Resource file and declared its name as youtubefragment1.xml and added Youtubeplayer view in it.
2. Created a new class file with the following code in it.

public class youtubeFragment1 extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment  {

```
private String currentVideoID = "video_id";
private YouTubePlayer activePlayer;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.youtubefragmen1,container,false);

    return view;

}


public static youtubeFragment1 newInstance(String url) {

    youtubeFragment1 youtubeFragment1 = new youtubeFragment1();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("url", url);

    youtubeFragment1.setArguments(bundle);

    return youtubeFragment1;
}

private void init() {
    final String DeveloperKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

    initialize(DeveloperKey, new OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) { }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
            activePlayer = player;
            activePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
            if (!wasRestored) {
                activePlayer.loadVideo(getArguments().getString("url"), 0);

            }
        }
    });
}

public void onYouTubeVideoPaused() {
    activePlayer.pause();
}
```

3. The YouTubePlayerFragment and its attributes are as shown below.
4. I declared a fragment in the main activity and set its attributes.

Is the code that I've written thus far correct? How do I link the YouTube fragment with the fragment declared in the main activity?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do not use `YouTubePlayerView` directly. Use YouTubePlayerFragment as recommended by Google [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment). All you need to do is place two `YouTubePlayerFragment`s in your activity layout and call `initialize(String, OnInitializedListener)` on both from your activity to create corresponding `YouTubePlayer`s which you can use to load videos into the fragments.

Also, all the code you might need is provided in [the samples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications).

> Is the code that I've written thus far correct?

It may be syntactically correct, but it defeats the purpose of `YouTubePlayerFragment`. A `YouTubePlayerFragment` takes care of generating its own `YouTubePlayerView` and handles all required life cycle changes in its own life cycle callbacks. In your code, you have *created and returned your own `YouTubePlayerView` in `onCreateView()`*, which will not be handled by these callbacks. So, as far as I can tell, this code seems like a wrong way to use `YouTubePlayerFragment`.

> How do I link the YouTube fragment with the fragment declared in the main activity?

I don't understand what you mean. In general, to use a fragment, you declare it in the activity's layout XML file. Then, get a reference inside your activity like this

```
YouTubePlayerFragment youTubePlayerFragment =
        (YouTubePlayerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment);
```

To solve your original problem, just declare two `YouTubePlayerFragment`s in your activity's layout file with different id's:

```
<fragment
      android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
      android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment_1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<fragment
      android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
      android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment_2"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And get references to both inside your activity:

```
YouTubePlayerFragment fragment1, fragment2;
fragment1 = (YouTubePlayerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment_1);
fragment2 = (YouTubePlayerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment_2);
```

Now call initialize() on both fragments whenever it needs to play.

Again, all code is in [the samples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications) I linked to. Please download and go through it.

Comment: thankyou @bitbybit i was using YoutubePlayerFragments only and could you tell me a bit more clearly as i had mentioned it already i am new here.and is my code of the fragment all correct?? and how sould i implement the youtube player fragment in my main activity?? ThankYou.

Comment: @PrudhviReddy Your fragment code is a wrong way to use the `YouTubePlayerFragment`. I've added further details to the answer. Try to complete the code and run it on a device. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thankyou @bitbybit.You had explained it very well really but to be frank as i am very beginner here i didn't really get u and the samples also they are explaining the methods but i coudn't figure out what to be used where.I know how it feels to explain to a laymen but be with me i can take it.

Comment: k now can u please make it a bit clear i had updated the code as you had said my previous code was wrong and the name of this file is YoutubeFragment1.java now i added a YouTubePlayerFragment in youtubefragment1.xml which had been inflated in YoutubeFragment1.java as shown above. with the following code as been updated in the question.Now how should i call this from my main activity and pass the video URL as the argument.Thank you @bitbybit

Comment: <fragment
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="200dp"
android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
android:id="@+id/YoutubeFragment"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />This is the code i had used for  YouTubePlayerFragment..